# How to open or launch PDF Files in C#.Net?

Tags: c#, filestream, .net

How do I launch a PDF Programmatically from a C# application in it's own process?

Originally: I want to open PDF file when i click button in C#.Net?

Comment: do you need to open it for reading? editing? image extraction? PDFToolkit is what I normally use for all that stuff, dunno if you can use it in c# tho

Answer (score 130):

I assume you just want to open the file. Try the following

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"c:\file.pdf");
```

Comment: Mark the ans right, if you get it. It helps others

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean for "open PDF file"? If you need to read all byties more simple method is:

```
byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"c:\file.pdf");
```

If you want display its on WinForm - look [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/781117/display-pdf-in-winform-c)

Answer (score 1):

to give the third possible answer to your question:

if you want to edit the PDF-file you can use a library like [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) or [PDFSharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net)