# Read PDF in C# or any other language

Tags: c#, pdf, language-agnostic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PDF Libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210029/pdf-libraries)
>   [How to open PDF Files in C#.Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742720/how-to-open-pdf-files-in-c-net)

I am making a application which can read pdf in C#. till now i can just create the pdf using

```
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
```

Is there any Api or some other language by which i can read pdf's.

Comment: Please state your requirements more exactly. If you simply want to read a PDF file (e.g. to write it somewhere else), simply use a file stream. If instead you want to extract certain PDF specific data, please explain. Do you only want to access some attributes? Do you want the text or images on the pages? Do you want to copy whole pages?

Comment: i want to compare two pdf's

Comment: In which way do you want to compare them? Just comparing field values of some forms? Or actually comparing the whole PDF? In the latter case you will have to pin down your requirements somewhat, cf. the comments to the answers of [iText API for PDF comparison](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703190/itext-api-for-pdf-comparison).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Adobe PDF IFilter**](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/detail.jsp?ftpID=2611) is a free downloadable Dynamic Link Library (DLL) file that provides a bridge between a Microsoft indexing client and a library of Adobe PDF files. It consists of code that understands the Adobe Portable Document Format as well as code that can interface with the indexing client. When an indexing client needs to index content from PDF files, it will look in its registry for an appropriate DLL and will find the Adobe PDF IFilter. Adobe PDF IFilter will return text to the indexing client. The indexing client will then index the results and return the appropriate results to the user.

**Article about use of this** : [**Converting PDF to Text in C#**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12445/Converting-PDF-to-Text-in-C)

Comment: do u have any idea about PDF Clown.. http://www.stefanochizzolini.it/en/projects/clown/

Answer (score 0):

You can see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340278/reading-pdf-in-c-sharp)
and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411610/programmatic-reading-of-pdfs-in-c-sharp) this question is already asked...
also you can convert PDF to text and then read it's content